# Simple accordion callback function

Tags: html, angular, function, accordion

I have simple accordion that i would like to open one field and close all others on click, and do that for each fealds too. I have an array of sections (name of fields). What i need is to create functions, one to set value of activeSection, and other to return current value of activeSection.

```
<div *ngFor="let section of sections">
    <div class="element-div1" (click)="switchelement()">{{section}}</div>
    <div class="element-box-div" *ngIf="activeSection==section"></div>
</div>
```

and in component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component( {
    selector: 'element-resources',
    templateUrl: './element-resources.component.html',
    styles: []
} )
export class ElementResourcesComponent implements OnInit {

    sections=["E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5"];

    activeSection = "E3";

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    switchelement (section) {
        ;
    }
}
```

I know there is easy version to use ngIf, but I need it this way with callback function. If you could help, and tell me what should I change and write, I would be very grateful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass current `section`(current iteration value) to `click` event

```
(click)="switchelement(section)"
```

and then assign it to `activeSection` from `switchelement` method.

```
activeSection: string;

switchelement (section: string) {
    this.activeSection = section;
}
```

Comment: Not really related to this topic, but, could you tell me how could i change background color of first div on this click, and whenever i click on other field, and reset color to previous. Thanks

Comment: @VladimirTomasevicMyNameIsVLT apply class based on `activeSesion`, you could use `ngClass` directive like `[ngClass]="{'active': activeSection==section}"`